# Convert for loop which calls different functions to a generator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, generator

I am reading a list of csv's, performing computations, and writing the output to drive. The dataset is large (2 gb csv on 16gb RAM), the calculation is expensive and output is also large. Therefore I want to use a generator; so that I can write my output file one at a time. The functions I have used are big, hence not pasting them here. I think a generator with the final for loop will do the job.

```
#read csv with indexing, uecols, dtypes ~ 1 DF is approx 50mb in memory
def reader_1sec_csv(filepath,.....):
    return pd.read_csv(filepath,........)

#processing df
def booleans (dataframe):
    dataframe = dataframe[....]
    ....
    ....
    return dataframe

#processing, row by row operation
def activity (row):
    val = "Unknown"
    ...
    ...
    return val

#apply the functions to a list of filepaths and write to outdir
def csv_to_result (filepath, outdir =".."):
    dataframe = booleans(reader_1sec_csv(filepath))
    dataframe["Activity"] = dataframe.apply(activity, axis=1)
    out = dataframe[["Activity"]]
    out.to_csv(os.path.join(outdir, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath))[0]+'_A.csv'))

#Can I make this into a generator? Keeping the exceptions list?
exceptions = []
for i in filepaths:
    try:
        csv_to_outcsv(i)
    except:
        exceptions.append(i)
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am appending list of exceptions. So I set the program to run after every 5mins using `time` module. Because it's not going to be easy to define all the exceptions inside the generator.

```
exceptions_list = []
def gen_out(paths):

    for i in paths:
        try:
            yield csv_to_outcsv(i)
        except:
            exceptions_list.append(i)
            continue

def periodic_work(interval):
    while True:
        next(gen_out(filepaths)
        time.sleep(interval)
```